# Return a pointer on multidimensional array c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to make a function who return a pointer on a mutidimensional array (cause we can't return an array in cpp) but I don't know how to do this.
I have this error
./source/code/metier/Jeu.cpp: In member function ‘Tuile** Jeu::getPlateau()’:
./source/code/metier/Jeu.cpp:21:10: error: cannot convert ‘Tuile* (*)[6][9]’ to ‘Tuile**’ in return
return p;

I'm looking for an issue but I really don't find

Here is my code
Jeu.hpp

```
#ifndef JEU_H
#define JEU_H

#include "./Tuile.hpp"
#include <memory>

class Jeu
{
private:
  static constexpr int LARGEUR  = 6;
  static constexpr int LONGUEUR = 9;

  std::shared_ptr<Tuile> sPierre ;
  std::shared_ptr<Tuile> sPoisson;
  std::shared_ptr<Tuile> sBois   ;
  std::shared_ptr<Tuile> sVide   ;

  Tuile* plateauTuile[LARGEUR][LONGUEUR];
  void chargerPlateau(int);
public:
  Jeu(int);
  ~Jeu();

  Tuile** getPlateau();
  
  inline static const int getLargeur (){ return Jeu::LARGEUR ; }
  inline static const int getLongueur(){ return Jeu::LONGUEUR; }
};

#endif
```

Jeu.cpp

```
#include "./Jeu.hpp"

Jeu::Jeu(int iNumPlateau)
{
  Jeu::sPierre  = std::make_shared<Tuile> ("PIERRE" );
  Jeu::sPoisson = std::make_shared<Tuile> ("POISSON");
  Jeu::sBois    = std::make_shared<Tuile> ("BOIS"   );
  Jeu::sVide    = std::make_shared<Tuile> ();
  
  Jeu::chargerPlateau(iNumPlateau );
}

Jeu::~Jeu()
{
  std::cout << "Je suis détruit JEU" << std::endl;
}

Tuile** Jeu::getPlateau()
{
  auto* p = &plateauTuile;
  return p;
}

void Jeu::chargerPlateau(int iNumPlateau)
{
  for ( int i=0;i<Jeu::LARGEUR; i++ )
    for ( int j=0;j<Jeu::LONGUEUR; j++)Jeu::plateauTuile[i][j] = Jeu::sVide.get();

  if ( iNumPlateau == 1 )
  {
    Jeu::plateauTuile[0][0] = Jeu::sPierre.get();
    Jeu::plateauTuile[0][3] = Jeu::sPierre.get();
    Jeu::plateauTuile[0][7] = Jeu::sPierre.get();
    Jeu::plateauTuile[0][8] = Jeu::sPierre.get();

    Jeu::plateauTuile[0][5] = Jeu::sPoisson.get();
    Jeu::plateauTuile[2][0] = Jeu::sPoisson.get();
    Jeu::plateauTuile[3][8] = Jeu::sPoisson.get();
    Jeu::plateauTuile[5][4] = Jeu::sPoisson.get();
    Jeu::plateauTuile[5][5] = Jeu::sPoisson.get();

    Jeu::plateauTuile[0][2] = Jeu::sBois.get();
    Jeu::plateauTuile[3][0] = Jeu::sBois.get();
    Jeu::plateauTuile[4][6] = Jeu::sBois.get();
    Jeu::plateauTuile[5][1] = Jeu::sBois.get();
    Jeu::plateauTuile[5][2] = Jeu::sBois.get();
    Jeu::plateauTuile[5][8] = Jeu::sBois.get();
  }
  else
  {

  }
}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: The variable `plateauTuile` is an array of arrays of `Tuile*`, its type is `Tuile* [LARGEUR][LONGUEUR]`. That means `&plateauTuile` will have the type `Tuile* (*)[LARGEUR][LONGUEUR]`. Very different from `Tuile**`. In short, only is a few cases will an array of arrays decay to a pointer to a pointer. I suggest you use `std::array` instead, and return a reference.

Comment: ***"cause we can't return an array in cpp"*** - You can, just not the *low-level native* arrays. You can use `std::array` for example.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I'm learning c++ by myself and I honestly want to use a native rray for have a better knowledge about us. However I can't fix my bug, eve if I change the return type in my hpp and cpp files, could you help me pls again ?

Comment: I write this in my header file```Tuile* (*)[LARGEUR][LONGUEUR] getPlateau();``` but I have this error.         error: expected unqualified-id before ‘)’ token
   Tuile* (*)[LARGEUR][LONGUEUR] getPlateau();
            ^
./source/code/./metier/Jeu.hpp:24:31: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
   Tuile* (*)[LARGEUR][LONGUEUR] getPlateau();
                               ^
./source/code/./metier/Jeu.hpp:24:44: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘getPlateau’ with no type [-fpermissive]
   Tuile* (*)[LARGEUR][LONGUEUR] getPlateau();

Comment: @BenjiHS it's because of C syntax of declaration is spiraling. You have to write that as `Tuile (*foo()) [LARGEUR][LONGUEUR]`, but it's more readable to use type aliases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I was able to get it compiling by creating typedefs:

```
class Jeu {
  ...
  using TuilePtr = Tuile*;
  using TuilePtrArray = TuilePtr[LARGEUR][LONGUEUR];
  TuilePtrArray plateauTuile;
  ...
  TuilePtrArray* getPlateau() { return &plateauTuile; }
}
```

I may have mixed up the types though, so if it's still failing let me know!

Comment: Hi eveyone thx for your answers,  I'm learning c++ and I don't see again the "chapter" about the typedefs and alias. However with this, it's compiling and more réadapter, so I will check this part now to have a better knowledge of the subject.

Comment: That’s odd that it’s not there. Typedefs (or more specifically `using` statements) are helpful ways to create nicknames for types. I’m sure there are resources online to learn more if you’re interested

Comment: It's not there because I learn in a book, (In french because I'm french), and there are 32 chapter about the c++ and it is the 29 chapter, but i'm currently at the 22